Net MAUI: The target(s) of [NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor] must be an accessible IRelayCommand property
CommunityToolkit.Maui ver 8.0.0
When adding the NotifyPropertyChangedFor attribute, an error occurs, although everything used is correct as on the page.
here is the page code:
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input; 

namespace uManageMobileApp.ViewModel
{

    public partial class BaseViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        [NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(SetBusy))]
        public bool isBusy = false;

        [ObservableProperty]
        [NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(SetBusy))]
        public string? busyLable = string.Empty;


        [RelayCommand]
        public async void Back()
        {
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"..");
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        public void SetBusy(string busyText)
        {
            this.IsBusy = true;
            this.BusyLable = busyText;
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        public void SetNotBusy()
        {
            this.IsBusy = false;
            this.BusyLable = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}


added attribute for the command ->  [RelayCommand]

You can refer to the official document about How the RelayCommand attribute works.
So you can change the [NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(SetBusy))] to [NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(SetBusyCommand))]. Such as:
[ObservableProperty]
[NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(SetBusyCommand))]
public bool isBusy = false;

[ObservableProperty]
[NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(SetBusyCommand))]
public string? busyLable = string.Empty;

